# Combine two animations together

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to combine two animations together :

running animation & Magic Attack animation

the problem is when Magic animation run the Character Legs stop running when I make Avatar Mask in unity to make legs do running animation and the upper body do Magic animation The character moves incorrectly

Here is the files (fbx) if anyone can combine it in right way:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EiBRqJyb4G-7AWr12naT4ijIOF5q4OFV?usp=sharing

Comment: [Blend Trees](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html). Also asking people on SO to just do work for you without any work is not responded to well. You just dumped the FBX files from a free asset and asked us to combine them. Do some research into `Blend Trees`. It is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't ask people to do work for me I uploaded the files so anyone can test it and if he got a solution. he can tell me how to do it ( just to get accurate answer ), I did a lot of searching for days but didn't get anything helpful to solve my problem.
The Blend trees is not the solution I want full running animation on legs and full magic attack animation on character upper body